# AirPlay Video without XBMC?

Tags: raspbian

I have my Raspberry Pi set up as an audio AirPlay server and I was wondering if it's possible to set it up to show video as well. I know that Raspbmc has this functionality, but I'd rather stick with Raspbian if possible.

I've found [forum posts](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2359972) alluding to a beta version of AirPlay mirroring software, but can't find any more information about it. The closest I've been able to find is [this video](http://9to5mac.com/2012/02/29/raspberry-pi-brings-airplay-video-streaming-for-25-preorder-now/) from 2012 where someone is running an app that allows video mirroring via AirPlay. There's no reference in the text. I've also Googled the name of the command that the gentleman in the video executes with no luck. The video suggests that it's possible though.

Does anyone know a way to do video AirPlay mirroring on a Raspberry Pi without running Raspbmc?

Comment: Note that this is only for unprotected content.

Comment: I also want to know how achieve it in the video without xbmc however.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I never managed to stream video from Apple to anything else properly. Please post an answer if you can

Comment: Not in Raspbian, but I've had limited success with Raspbmc. With Raspbmc half the time the pi doesn't show up as a AirPlay device or it crashes mid video. Admittedly, I haven't revisited this recently and I haven't tried it with a Pi2, so it might work better nowadays.

Comment: If your source device is on IOS9, I think it's not yet feasible to stream to xmbc/kodi. Thank Apple for their fantastic upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/FD-/RPiPlay

So far, this has worked for me. It mirrors your screen and audio like a charm, however streaming apps such as Youtube, Netflix, Prime Video etc. do not work. I imagine that their corresponding web versions might, however I have not tested it.

Answer (score -1):

Even xbmc won't support airplay mirroring, please wait for our rPlay software, will be available in August.

rPlay is doing beta testing right now.

http://www.vmlite.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&Itemid=158

This is a video:

http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=aviPOINM6Bk&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DaviPOINM6Bk

Comment: please, elaborate regarding `rPlay`? something like URL might be very helpful.

Comment: http://www.vmlite.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&Itemid=158&func=view&catid=23&id=10991

Comment: -1. This answer needs much more information!

Comment: We will release a beta to our early testers late next week. After that, there will be more info.

You can use XBMC to play videos, but that is regular AirPlay, i.e., audio/video/photos from some apps.  However, that is not AirPlay Mirroring. AirPlay mirroring is whatever you see on the screen will be shown on the TV, systematically, no matter what apps you are running. rPlay does AirPlay mirroring, the only software in town can do that for Pi.

Comment: It would be nice to have more information about the project of yours. Where's the code hosted? Do you have a website? Googling for rPlay just gives a Java AirPlay implementation.

Comment: Check our forum at http://www.vmlite.com, about 1000 pi users are beta testing rPlay now.

Comment: please do elaborate on your answer, just posting project names and URLs that might be dead in a few weeks isn't helpful.

Comment: Obviously this project is dead. Also it was asked to playback video (with audio as with movies) and not screen mirroring.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://jerrygamblin.com/2015/05/09/rplay-is-spying-on-you/