# Stream Airplay Video to Raspberry Pi without raspbmc

Tags: raspbian, streaming-video

I know, basically this question has already been asked two years ago ([AirPlay Video without XBMC?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8487/airplay-video-without-xbmc)). But I'd like to know what's the up-to-date status on that question.

I want to stream audio and video from my iOS/OSX devices to my RaspberryPi with minimal footprint, i.e., without xbmc or a full gnome installation (totem has a no-longer-maintained plugin for receiving airplay).

What i have in mind is an application that i can run on a bare xserver installation without any window managers or desktop environments such that the RaspberryPi can quickly boot and (without any user interaction) display video content streamed using apple airplay.

Is there anything like that out there?

Comment: My question is no duplicate. The post you refer to is about Airplay audio streaming whether my question is about Airplay video(!) streaming.

Comment: You admit it is a duplicate in your first sentence

Comment: Yea... but the question is dead for nearly one year now...

Comment: *"What applications can I use to stream Airplay video to?"* ->
Apparently, [at least Kodi](http://kodi.wiki/view/AirPlay).  It does not depend upon GNOME or RaspMC and is available in Raspbian.  *"Can I run an application such as Kodi on a bare X server without a DE or WM?"* -> Yes, it is pretty simple, look into **xinitrc**.  *"Can I start an X server to do what I want at boot?"* -> Yes, the GUI login does.

Answer (score 2):

Kodi **was** able to do this.
However since IOS 9, Apple has decided to work some magic to make this feature go away on all non-apple TV devices. There are some Github projects out there that are working on reverse engineering Apples work done in IOS9, but last I checked it wasn't done yet.

All devices running an older IOS should still be able to stream.

[Link](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=238523)

Answer (score 0):

Use [**UV4L**](http://linux-projects.org). It can stream live audio and/or video (+ optionally two-way) with no delay to a Raspberry Pi connected to speakers and/or HDMI display or touchscreen. It works out of the box without any particular configuration from any browser, smartphone, tablet. An X server is not necessary. You should be able to select the Video Input Source from the browser directly or write a simple HTML5 page with some JavaScript to choose the preferred video source.  Here is a [screenshot](http://www.linux-projects.org/downloads/screenshots/webrtc-twoway.png).